# How Can I show all orders of mode by using proc univariate

Tags: sas

I try to show all orders of Mode.

For example, I import excel like:

```
A

1

1

2

3

3

3
```

and code is :

```
ods select Modes;
proc univariate data=Want modes;
   var A;
run;
```

this **Result** shows like:

```
   Mode  Count
    3     3
```

I want to show like

```
Mode  Count
3     3
1     2
2     1
```

how can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is actually not modes. Modes returns most frequent value or values (if there is more than one with the same frequency) with the corresponding count. In your example, there is only one mode (3), as it is the value with the highest frequency. And that's what the result shows.

You may be interested in showing frequencies of every value present in variable A.  In that case, you want to use this code:

```
ods select Frequencies;
proc univariate data=Want freq;
   var A;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a frequency table.

```
data have ;
  input A @@;
cards;
1 1 2 3 3 3
;

proc freq data=have order=freq ;
  tables a / out=counts;
run;
proc print data=counts;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    A    COUNT    PERCENT

 1     3      3      50.0000
 2     1      2      33.3333
 3     2      1      16.6667
```